# Can't resolve all parameters for WinwheelService: (?, ?)

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I have an Winwheel service like this

```
@Injectable()
export class WinwheelService {

  constructor(options, drawWheel) {}

}
```

then i am initializing this service in my app component like this

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initWheel();
  }

  initWheel() {

    this.wheel = new Winwheel({
      'numSegments': 8,   // Specify number of segments.
      'outerRadius': 212,  // Set radius to so wheel fits the background.
      'innerRadius': 150,  // Set inner radius to make wheel hollow.
      'pointerAngle': 90,
      'pointerGuide':        // Turn pointer guide on.
      {
        'display': true,
        'strokeStyle': 'red',
        'lineWidth': 3
      },
      'segments':       // Define segments including colour and text.
      [
        { 'fillStyle': '#eae56f', 'text': 'Prize 1' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#89f26e', 'text': 'Prize 2' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#7de6ef', 'text': 'Prize 3' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#e7706f', 'text': 'Prize 4' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#eae56f', 'text': 'Prize 5' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#89f26e', 'text': 'Prize 6' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#7de6ef', 'text': 'Prize 7' },
        { 'fillStyle': '#e7706f', 'text': 'Prize 8' }
      ],
      'animation':           // Define spin to stop animation.
      {
        'type': 'spinToStop',
        'duration': 5,
        'spins': 8,
        'callbackFinished': this.alertPrize()
      }
    }, true);
  }
}
```

But initializing my service like this gives me following error

```
Can't resolve all parameters for WinwheelService: (?, ?)
```

What is the other way to initialize a class with parameters.

Comment: are you using barrel?? to import the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i am initializing an object of my service class, rather than injecting it in the component, so there is no need to register it inside the providers it the app module.

There is also other way of doing this, [click here to know more about this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#dependency-injection-tokens)